# How to get/load an existing user in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I have created a user in ASP.NET Core Identity.
Now I want to be able to load it.

I know I have `userManager.GetUserAsync` that takes a principal. But I want to be able to load it using different parameters. For example `Id` and `Email` and `Username`.

I want this method. `var user = userManager.GetUser(userId);`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the usermanager has build method which could get the username according to identity user's property.

More details about how to read the user according to identity user property, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;

            _logger = logger;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //read by Email
            var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == "brandotest@aaa.com");
            //read by ID
            var user2 = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "xxxxx");
            //read by username
            var user3 = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "xxxxx");

            return View();
        }
   }
```

Result:

[image]